# Angular Routing always show url before component

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, routes, guard

I don't know what happen, but in my Angular 7 apps when i input some url via browser it's always following url that i'm typing.
Example :

typing => http://localhost:4200/xxx

result => http://localhost:4200/xxx/dashboard

typing => http://localhost:4200/ooo

result => http://localhost:4200/ooo/dashboard

in RouteTracing url **xxx** or **ooo** cannot be read, NavigationStartUrl it's always "/" (image attached)

here's my AuthGuard :

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    const currentUser = this.service.currentUserValue;
    if (currentUser) {
        let roles = route.data['allowedRoles'] as Array<string>;
        if(roles){
            roles.forEach(role=>{
                if(currentUser.URole == role){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    this.router.navigateByUrl('/forbidden');
                    return false;
                }
            })
        }
        return true;
    }else{
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
        return false;
    }
}
```

and here's is my AppRoute :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'',redirectTo:'dashboard',pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'dashboard',component:DashboardComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'section',component:SectionComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'subsection',component:SubsectionComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'equipment',component:EquipmentComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'downtime',component:DowntimeComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'user',component:UserComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard],data:{allowedRoles:['Admin']}},
  {path:'mainfailure',component:MainfailureComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'failureaction',component:FailureactionComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'failuremechanism',component:FailuremechanismComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'failuremode',component:FailuremodeComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'failurecause',component:FailurecauseComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'login',component:LoginComponent},
  {path:'forbidden',component:ForbiddenComponent},
  {path:'**',redirectTo:'dashboard'}
];
```

i enable tracing in routes but every xxx that's i input to browser always say it's "/" here's the log :
[Routes Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmABZ.png)

Comment: Please, show an exemple of button or link that redirects to the dashboard.

Comment: @PedroLima when accessing via link it's OK, but when i typing in browser url, input is always following, ex : http:/localhost:4200/dosa then browser url result is http:localhost:4200/dosa/home/dashboard

Answer (score 0):

This guide for [Setting up redirects](https://angular.io/guide/router#setting-up-redirects), from the official Angular website, puts the redirect **after** the target redirect route and **before** the wildcard route, so maybe you should try this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'dashboard',component:DashboardComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'section',component:SectionComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'subsection',component:SubsectionComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'equipment',component:EquipmentComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'downtime',component:DowntimeComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'user',component:UserComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard],data:{allowedRoles:['Admin']}},
  {path:'mainfailure',component:MainfailureComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'failureaction',component:FailureactionComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'failuremechanism',component:FailuremechanismComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'failuremode',component:FailuremodeComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'failurecause',component:FailurecauseComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'login',component:LoginComponent},
  {path:'forbidden',component:ForbiddenComponent},
  {path:'',redirectTo:'dashboard',pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'**',redirectTo:'dashboard'}
];
```

Comment: thanks, well after search so long, the problem is not in routemodule or auth, i accidently change base href in index.html from '/' to ''

Answer (score 0):

thanks, well after search so long, the problem is not in routemodule or auth, i accidently change base href in index.html from '/' to ''